# Under what conditions does a non-empty intersection over $\mathbb{Z}$ remain non-empty after a change of base ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $V$ be a Zariski open subset of an affine variety over $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $f: V \to P$ be a morphism into a projective space $P$ over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Assume there given a projective hypersurface $Z \subset P$ given by the vanishing of a homogeneous polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and that

$f(V) \cap Z = \phi$

We would like to consider these objects over a commutative ring $A$ with $1$, in which $-1$ is not a square. If we now let $V_A$ be the variety $V$ defined now over $A$, let $P_A$ and $Z_A$ be the projective varieties $P$ and $Z$ respectively defined now over $A[i]$, and denote by

$f_A: V_A \to P_A$

the map corresponding to $f$. Under what conditions on $V$, $P$, $f$ and $A$, do we have

$f_A(V_A) \cap Z_A = \phi$ ?

Comment: Always? If $B\cap C = \varnothing$ then $A\times B \cap A\times C = \varnothing$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ben, I have thought about what you wrote. Consider the following. Let $f$ be the map from the affine line $V$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ into $P^1$, which maps any point to the point $[1:3]$. Assume that $Z = \{[1:0]\}$. We have that $f(V) \cap Z = \phi$, but after reducing mod $3$, i.e. taking $A$ to be the integers modulo $3$, we get that the intersection is no longer empty.

Comment: I have to admit that I have used the word "extension" which was probably confusing. I meant a change of base ring, which is not necessarily an extension of $\mathbb{Z}$. I will fix that.